# how to read attributes for given DN in ldap3 (how to search with ldap3 if no filter)

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

If I already have an LDAP DN, how do I get the attributes for that DN with `ldap3.Connection.search()`? There is no other search criteria, I already have the DN...

I tried searching for dn attribute, but it returned no objects found. I also tried forcing `search_filter` to `''`, `'()'` or `None` and they all returned malformed filter string.

I also couldn't find a way to do this with the abstract Reader...

In `ldapsearch` you don't need to specify a search filter if you are doing a baseDN lookup...

```
import ldap3

ldap_conn = ldap3.Connection('ldapserver', raise_exceptions=True, 
    auto_bind=True, user='me', password='mypassword')

my_dn = "attrib1=blahblah, ou=org1, dc=dc1, dc=dcroot"

ldap_conn.search(
    search_base=my_dn,
    search_filter= '(????)', # required
    search_scope=ldap3.BASE,
    attributes='*'
)

print(ldap_conn.response)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just realized that `objectClass` will always be present, so setting it to wildcard should shim search_filter to return the 1 entry associated with base DN:

```
ldap_conn.search(
    search_base=my_dn,
    search_filter= '(objectClass=*)', # required
    search_scope=ldap3.BASE,
    attributes='*'
)
```

However it seems silly there is no special case for LOOKUP operation against the connection given a DN in ldap3.

**EDIT**: @cannatag mentioned this was a limitation of the protocol, so I decided to check the RFC: [(RFC 4511)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5.1). Apparently, `ldapsearch` and Active Directory emulate an x.500-style LIST or READ by setting an `objectClass` presence filter :

> Note that an X.500 "list"-like operation can be emulated by the
> client requesting a singleLevel Search operation with a filter
> checking for the presence of the 'objectClass' attribute, and that an
> X.500 "read"-like operation can be emulated by a baseObject Search
> operation with the same filter.  A server that provides a gateway to
> X.500 is not required to use the Read or List operations, although it
> may choose to do so, and if it does, it must provide the same
> semantics as the X.500 Search operation.

Comment: It’s how the ldap protocol works. You must always set a filter when performing a search.

Comment: Ahh I found it in the RFC